# Comer y beber como animales

Tags: modismos

En todos los idiomas se producen comparaciones con animales para expresar que una persona come o bebe mucho.

En inglés, conozco las expresiones *to drink like a fish* y *to eat like a horse*.

En España he oído los modismos **“beber como un camello”** y **“comer como un animal”** (sin precisar qué animal). ¿Son las únicas posibilidades? ¿Alguien ha usado u oído comparaciones con otros animales?

Comment: Varios amigos me comentan que no consideran un modismo "beber como un camello", giro que desconocían. Google confirma el escaso uso de la expresión. Yo lo he oído desde mi infancia. Será un localismo o un giro particular de la familia. Me dicen mis amigos que lo que se dice es "beber como un cosaco", pero los cosacos no son animales...

Comment: en casa beber como un camello es beber mucha agua de golpe, beber como un cosaco es beber mucho alcohol.

Answer (score 3):

**Español**

En México se usa mucho que cuando alguien, particularmente un niño pero también se usa con adultos :), come y su lugar queda muy sucio se dice:

> Comes como pollito

**English**

In Mexico is very common that when someone, particularly children but it happens with some adults as well :), eats and his place gets very dirty you can say:

> Comes como pollito (You eat like a baby chicken)

Answer (score 3):

"Comer como un pajarito" en España es comer muy poquito.

Answer (score 1):

Todas estas son expresiones latinoamericanas:

> Comer como un cerdo: (Comer sin tener en cuenta lo que se come, o
>   comer comida totalmente insana, o comer sin tener un fin)
>
> Comer como una hormiga: Asociado a la conducta anorexica, que
>   desmenuza todo y solo selecciona lo mejor tomandose demasiado tiempo
>   para hacerlo.
>
> Comer como un elefante: comer grandes cantidades.
>
> Comer como un perro: comer de mala manera, con mal ánimo, o en malas circunstancias. Viene de "a cara de perro".
>
> Comer como mono: referido a la homosexualidad, despectivo. Ser
>   homosexual (no asociado al acto en si de comer)

Luego hay otros vulgarismos en diferentes argots no asociados a los animales:

> Comer como lija nueva: rapido y sustancioso, con mucho hambre.
>
> Beber como esponja nueva: beber demasiado.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Intenta cuidar el formato de las respuestas. Aquí solemos usar el estilo "cita" para ejemplos en vez de el de "código fuente". Esperamos verte a menudo preguntando y respondiendo :)

Comment: Je gracias por los consejos y la bienvenida, es que vengo de stackoverflow y estoy acostumbrado, lo tendre en cuenta. Soy profesor en letras y trabajo como programador (amplia mis conocimientos en mi hobby fundamental, neurolinguistica). Espero ayudar en lo que pueda, me pregunto si hay un sitio donde preguntar sobre ingles a nativos de ingles en español, porque si uno busca una expresion, es dificil encontrarla salvo en wordreference y muchas son malas.

Comment: "Beber como una esponja" se ajustaría a la pregunta, puesto que una esponja también es un animal... :)

Comment: jajjaja ciertamente, no lo habia pensado asi

Comment: @Leandro por desgracia no conozco salvo wordreference, y coincido en que muchas veces no son correctas...